# how to avoid crash when data is missing and throw exeption in flutter

Tags: flutter, error-handling

here is my code to catch data from web:

it crashes with multiple kind of exeptions each time, i want to show the error on screen but do not crash the app and terminate it

```
Future<SCoin> fetchCoinData(int giveMeIndex) async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  final jsonresponse = json.decode(response.body);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
for (var i in jsonresponse) {
  var coinItem = SCoin(
      name: i['name'],
      image: i['image'],
      current_price: i['current_price']);
  coins.add(coinItem);
}
return SCoin.fromJson(jsonresponse[giveMeIndex]);
} else {
throw Exception(response.statusCode);
 }
}
```

and this my widget to show data:

```
FutureBuilder<SCoin>(
                                                future: fetchCoinData(2),
                                                builder:
                                                    (context, snapshot) {
                                                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                                    return Column(
                                                      children: [
                                                        Container(
                                                          width: 45,
                                                          height: 45,
                                                          child: Image.network(
                                                              snapshot.data!
                                                                  .coinImage),
                                                        ),
                                                        Text(snapshot
                                                            .data!.name),
                                                        Text(snapshot.data!
                                                            .current_price
                                                            .toString())
                                                      ],
                                                    );
                                                  } else if (snapshot
                                                      .hasError) {
                                                    return Text(
                                                        '${snapshot.error}');
                                                  }

                                                  // By default, show a loading spinner.
                                                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                                                }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is done with the `try` and `catch` to try running a code, if there is any error you can evaluate and catch it, and the future you set to the `FutureBuilder`
should be wrapped inside another function that tries it and then catch on error like :

```
Future tryCatchMethod(int number) async {

try {
await fetchCoinData(number);
} on Exception catch(error) {
// Here throw you exceptions and take actions based on your needs
}}
```

and assigning that new method to the `FutureBuilder`

```
future: tryCatchMethod;
```

this will try running your Future method, if it succeeds, then nothing will happen, normally, but if something wrong happened and an error threw it will execute the catch block code.

Comment: Its working thanks but one more thing, how to say resend the request? I'm getting infinite circularProgressIndicator

Comment: give me more info about that problem so I can help with it also

Comment: however, a force SetSatate will reBuild the FutureBuilder which will cause a reload

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Future<SCoin> fetchCoinData(int giveMeIndex) async {
  try {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final jsonresponse = json.decode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      for (var i in jsonresponse) {
      var coinItem = SCoin(
        name: i['name'],
        image: i['image'],
        current_price: i['current_price'],
      );
      coins.add(coinItem);
      }
      return SCoin.fromJson(jsonresponse[giveMeIndex]);
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.statusCode);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw Exception(e);
  }
}
```